# WSS3, InfoPath 2007, Active Directory Web Service

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, wss-3.0, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

Windows Server 2008 SP2 (Non R2), .net Framework 3.5 + patch for ADWS, IIS7 all present on the PDC.

What is the default URI for the service?  It cannot be found even with firewall switched off.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the non R2 version does not support http binding

Answer (score 0):

net.tcp://DOMAINHERE:9389/ActiveDirectoryWebServices/mex